# How to use socket programming on JSP to access data base from another computer.....any method?

Tags: java, html, jsp, sockets

## i am working on a final year project

**i am developing a jsp website**
1- i have to connect three system's
2-Two of them are having databases and on third computer there is a jsp page which will access data from both databases simultaneously
3-what programming code should i apply
and how to connect these three computers
any help is greatly appreciated
Thankyou

Comment: *“what programming code should i apply”* If we just *give* you that, you'd be plagiarizing for your project. Do you have any attempts that can be fixed?

Comment: no sir we wwre first thinking about socket programming. bot now we got comment that we cant use socket programming directly on jsp. we have to use servlet. we dont know what to do.

Comment: "Can't"?   That's too strong.  You can do anything you want.  I'm recommending that you try something a little smarter.  You don't know what to do?  Figure out how my suggestion can work with your use case or start writing that socket stuff.

Comment: if any one can give code hint then please help us

Comment: You've already gotten a hint; you're just not smart enough to act on it.

Answer (score 2):

JSP should *not* be accessing any databases directly

Write a servlet for the JSP to talk to.  Give the servlet JDBC connections to the two databases.  Let it interact with the DBs on the JSP's behalf and send it results to display.

*No sockets*.  Use JDBC.

```
                       +-----> DB1 via JDBC
                       |
JSP ----> servlet -----+
                       |
                       +-----> DB2 via JDBC
```